# Seleccionar un solo componente usando SelectAll

Tags: typescript, electron, vuejs

Me explico.
Estoy usando Electron + Vuejs + Typescript, entonces la situación es que quiero seleccionar un solo componente usando el SelectAll, ahora mismo estoy usando el SelectAll del menu de electron, pero me selecciona toda la pantalla y necesito seleccionar la información del componente en el que me encuentro.

Alguna Idea? Gracias

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Encontre esta solución con javascript.

```
function seleccionaTexto(element){
    var doc = document,
    text = doc.getElementById(element),
    range,
    selection;
    if(doc.body.createTextRange){ //ms
        range = doc.body.createTextRange();
        range.moveToElementText(text);
        range.select();
    }else if(window.getSelection){ //all others
        selection = window.getSelection();
        range = doc.createRange();
        range.selectNodeContents(text);
        selection.removeAllRanges();
     selection.addRange(range);
    }
}
```

http://www.danielmayor.com/javascript-como-selecionar-un-texto-usando-javascript-cross-browser